# using "this" in each function , how to use with different class

Tags: jquery

example below , i want to do something different if some of the #div has a unique class. I get error using hasClass and find

```
$('.div').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('span').length === 2){
        // this works
        }
    if($(this).hasClass('test').find('span').length === 1){
        // this doesnt work - error hasClass and find not a function - so how can i use this , but for a "this" with unique class ?
    }
});
```

This works fine on its own , but why cant i define in same function

```
$('.div .test').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('span').length === 1){
        // this works
    }
});
```

This does not work

```
$('.div').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('span').length === 2 || $(this).hasClass('test').find('span').length === 1 ){
        // error hasClass and find not a function
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What happens if you log `this` inside the function? In jQuery `$(this)` will refer to the jQ object under iteration; if `find`/`hasClass` aren't there, something is wrong.

Comment: getting hasClass and find is not a jquery function , .div does have the class of "test"

Comment: `hasClass` returns a boolean. What I *asked* was what happens when you log `this`, but you can't chain jQ functions off of a boolean regardless.

Comment: (Unrelated, but a class named `div` seems redundant. Do you mean `$('div')`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because [`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) returns a boolean, not a jQuery object, so you can't chain another jQuery method from that.

You can work around this by using `filter()` instead:

```js
if ($(this).filter('.test').find('span').length === 1) {
  // do something...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this condition instead:

> If ( $(this).hasClass('test') && $(this).find('span').length === 1) {

Comment: need to use "find" for both , and that is where the error is , error says hasClass and find is not a function

Comment: What am I missing here? Do You want to check if the div which has class 'test', has one child "span". Or do you want to check if the div has some span with class 'test' ?